# Trying to fetch data from data.json file into index.html file

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am creating a project in which I have two files index.html and data.json.
Now I want to fetch the JSON object into index.html for rendering.

But I am encountering cors error if I use `fetch()` method.

Is there any way to get the data from data.json ?

```
async fetchData(filename) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            return jsonData;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: use a web server ... browsers don't like fetching over `file://` protocol (you hid the URL too late) XMLHttpRequest won't work either - chrome has a command line flag to disable this behaviour, but you don't want to use that

Answer (score 2):

When working with local files using the `file://` protocol, modern browsers often enforce security restrictions, including CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policies. These restrictions are in place to prevent potential security vulnerabilities. Unfortunately, there's no direct way to disable or bypass CORS restrictions when loading local files via the file:// protocol.

However, you may consider alternative approaches if using a web server is not feasible:

1. Use a Browser Extension: Some browser extensions can override CORS policies for local files during development.
2. Use a Different Browser: Try using a browser that has less strict CORS policies in its local file handling.
3. Consider a Local Development Server: While a full web server might not be feasible, there are lightweight local development servers that you can run without installing anything globally. For example, you can use tools like `http-server` or `live-server` via Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opening the html file directly by double clicking? (The URL in your browser would look like this: file:///C:/Users/username/project/index.html)
The problem is that fetching ./data.json would access your file system which is prohibited due to security reasons. If you are using visual studio code you can install the  "live server" plugin. With that installed you could open your project as a folder in vscode and then right click on the index.html and choose "open with live server". After that the plugin should open your page in a new tab and the fetch call should be working, because the plugin is creating a static file server that serves your project files.